# Android inconsistent crashes

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, twilio

I'm building an ionic application, I had to use [this](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap) plugin in order to get the Twilio SDK to work. It was working, but without any reason I can put my finger on my app crashes when calling the Twilio.Device.connect.
when I'm debuging I can see the crash happens on native java code- on this line:

```
var msgs = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(bridgeSecret, service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
```

which is on the cordova.js file line 943.

what drives me crazy is the inconsistency, I cant tell what causing the crash!

here is the adb catlog:

```
> oc644369-2/lib/arm/libtwilio-native.so (Java_com_twilio_client_impl_useragent_Ca
ll_makeCall+174)
I/DEBUG   (  247):     #12 pc 000709fd  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.ioni
cframework.moneytunespoc644369-2@base.apk@classes.dex
W/AudioFlinger(  250): RecordThread: buffer overflow
I/AudioFlinger(  250): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4098) from active list on thread 0
xb59c7000
I/DEBUG   (  247):
I/DEBUG   (  247): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
I/BootReceiver(  773): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_
TOMBSTONE)
I/Choreographer(11192): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
h work on its main thread.
W/Thread-1259(11812): type=1701 audit(0.0:227): auid=4294967295 uid=10217 gid=10
217 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 reason="memory violation" sig=6
W/ActivityManager(  773):   Force finishing activity 1 com.ionicframework.moneyt
unespoc644369/.MainActivity
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202b
f}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
0}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
1}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x1050
104}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x1050
103}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x1050
103}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
2}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
7}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
c}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
8}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1201 a=1 r=0x1050
104}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x1050
103}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1801 a=1 r=0x1050
103}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
d}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
e}
I/WindowState(  773): WIN DEATH: Window{3195f6ed u0 com.ionicframework.moneytune
spoc644369/com.ionicframework.moneytunespoc644369.MainActivity}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
9}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x10202c
4}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x3001 a=1 r=0x1050
037}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x3001 a=1 r=0x1050
037}
W/Resources(  773): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x3001 a=1 r=0x1050
037}
D/OpenGLRenderer(  773): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/Atlas   (  773): Validating map...
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): in_standby: enter: stream (0xb586de80) usecase(7: aud
io-record)
I/ActivityManager(  773): Process com.ionicframework.moneytunespoc644369 (pid 11
192) has died
W/ActivityManager(  773): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.ionicframewo
rk.moneytunespoc644369/com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService in 84912ms
D/zyz     ( 2420): bar facade onStart
I/Test    ( 2420): onResume activeId: 1436976492097
D/hardware_info(  250): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = handset-mic
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): adev_close_input_stream: enter:stream_handle(0xb586de
80)
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): in_standby: enter: stream (0xb586de80) usecase(7: aud
io-record)
I/OpenGLRenderer(  773): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/zyz     ( 2420): onResume
I/zhiping ( 2420): weather resume
I/xiaojun ( 2420): lastChoosen : com.gau.go.launcherex
D/OpenGLRenderer(  773): Enabling debug mode 0
W/SurfaceFlinger(  240): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
I/Timeline( 2420): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@fa4fbae ti
me:257449
I/Zygote  (  260): Process 11192 exited due to signal (6)
V/ActivityManager(  773): killProcessGroupAsync took 221 ms for PID 11192 on thr
ead 17
I/Timeline(  773): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{3795af7
2 u0 com.gau.go.launcherex/com.jiubang.golauncher.GOLauncher t8668} time:257688
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): out_standby: enter: stream (0xb5880600) usecase(1: lo
w-latency-playback)
D/hardware_info(  250): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = handset
E/AudioTrack(  773): AudioTrack::set : Exit
V/PhoneStatusBar( 1166): setLightsOn(true)
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-pla
yback) kvpairs: routing=2
W/InputMethodManagerService(  773): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false)
 notification to pid 11192 uid 10217
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xb5880600)usecase
(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2)
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): start_output_stream: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-pl
ayback) devices(0x2)
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_dev
ice(0: )
W/msm8974_platform(  250): Codec backend bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000
D/hardware_info(  250): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
I/msm8974_platform(  250): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibr
ation for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 15, path =  0
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> send_adm_topology
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> send_asm_topology
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> send_audtable
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> send_audvoltable
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE
D/        (  250): Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000F

E/ACDB-LOADER(  250): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_VOL_CAL
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE
D/        (  250): Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000F

E/ACDB-LOADER(  250): Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
D/ACDB-LOADER(  250): ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL
D/audio_hw_primary(  250): select_devices: done
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
D/ConnectivityService(  773): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () -
 101] to 55
D/ConnectivityService(  773): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]
D/ConnectivityService(  773): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101] was alrea
dy satisfying request 1. No change.
D/ConnectivityService(  773): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI ()
 - 101]
D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 1166): CM callback handler got msg 524290

D/audio_hw_primary(  250): out_standby: enter: stream (0xb5880600) usecase(1: lo
w-latency-playback)
D/hardware_info(  250): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
D/ConnectivityService(  773): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () -
 101] to 56
D/ConnectivityService(  773): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]
D/ConnectivityService(  773): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101] was alrea
dy satisfying request 1. No change.
D/ConnectivityService(  773): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI ()
 - 101]
D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 1166): CM callback handler got msg 524290

D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
D/ConnectivityService(  773): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () -
 101] to 55
D/ConnectivityService(  773): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]
D/ConnectivityService(  773): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101] was alrea
dy satisfying request 1. No change.
D/ConnectivityService(  773): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI ()
 - 101]
D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 1166): CM callback handler got msg 524290

D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
I/art     (  773): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 130434(8MB)
AllocSpace objects, 174(3MB) LOS objects, 17% free, 38MB/46MB, paused 2.899ms to
tal 143.928ms
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
D/LBSSystemMonitorService(  773): handleMessage what - 4
D/Wiper_jni(  773): Send Network Location.
D/WifiResults(12170): Results Incomming
V/WoorldsWifiController( 6019): scanned APs: 10
I/WoorldsService( 6019): calling find to server: {"charge_state":"usb","networkI
nfo":{"networkLocation":{"accuracy":30.0,"latitude":32.08029,"longitude":34.7741
596}},"wifiNodes":[{"bssid":"80:37:73:d7:a3:f7","connectedObject":null,"encrypti
on":2,"mNetworkId":0,"powerLevel":-64,"ssid":"ShukronOhad15"}]}
D/Retrofit( 6019): ---> HTTP POST http://app.woorlds.com/api/find
D/Retrofit( 6019): Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/Retrofit( 6019): Content-Length: 254
D/Retrofit( 6019): {"charge_state":"usb","networkInfo":{"networkLocation":{"accu
racy":30.0,"latitude":32.08029,"longitude":34.7741596}},"wifiNodes":[{"bssid":"8
0:37:73:d7:a3:f7","connectedObject":null,"encryption":2,"mNetworkId":0,"powerLev
el":-64,"ssid":"ShukronOhad15"}]}
D/Retrofit( 6019): ---> END HTTP (254-byte body)
D/Retrofit( 6019): <--- HTTP 200 http://app.woorlds.com/api/find (396ms)
D/Retrofit( 6019): : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
D/Retrofit( 6019): Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-chec
k=0, pre-check=0
D/Retrofit( 6019): Connection: keep-alive
D/Retrofit( 6019): Content-Length: 202
D/Retrofit( 6019): Content-Type: application/json
D/Retrofit( 6019): Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 16:09:03 GMT
D/Retrofit( 6019): Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
D/Retrofit( 6019): Pragma: no-cache
D/Retrofit( 6019): Server: nginx
D/Retrofit( 6019): X-Android-Received-Millis: 1436976543217
D/Retrofit( 6019): X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
D/Retrofit( 6019): X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1436976543022
D/Retrofit( 6019): X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.41
D/Retrofit( 6019): {"wifiWorlds":[],"segmentations":{"803a064d-6b34-41a3-a283-59
8a22536f02":[{"id":"554f6c37223599407e8b456c","name":"cafe"}]},"campaigns":{"803
a064d-6b34-41a3-a283-598a22536f02":null},"nearby_woorlds":[]}
D/Retrofit( 6019): <--- END HTTP (202-byte body)
I/WoorldsService( 6019): find successful: {"customDataHashMap":null,"serverHost"
:null,"wifiWorlds":[],"campaigns":{"803a064d-6b34-41a3-a283-598a22536f02":null},
"notifications":null,"segmentations":{"803a064d-6b34-41a3-a283-598a22536f02":[{"
id":"554f6c37223599407e8b456c","name":"cafe"}]},"msg":null,"res_code":0,"status"
:false}, was in woorld: [none] now in:
I/WoorldsService( 6019): not in a woorld anymore, notifying wifi controller its
null for filtering
I/WoorldsWifiController( 6019): setting inwoorld bssid = null
V/WoorldsService( 6019): Publishing data to all services. WOORLDS_DATA:{"pluginV
ersion":466,"serverData":{"customDataHashMap":null,"serverHost":"http://app.woor
lds.com","wifiWorlds":[]}} EXTENDED_DATA: {"locationData":{"networkLocation":{"a
ccuracy":30.0,"latitude":32.08029,"longitude":34.7741596},"networkProviderEnable
d":false,"networkProviderStatus":null},"notificationEnabled":false,"wifiData":{"
connectedAccessPoint":null,"seenAccessPoints":[{"bssid":"80:37:73:d7:a3:f7","con
nectedObject":null,"encryption":2,"mNetworkId":0,"powerLevel":-64,"ssid":"Shukro
nOhad15"}],"wifiEnabled":true},"pluginVersion":466,"serverData":{"customDataHash
Map":null,"serverHost":"http://app.woorlds.com","wifiWorlds":[]}} SEGMENTATIONS:
 {"803a064d-6b34-41a3-a283-598a22536f02":[{"id":"554f6c37223599407e8b456c","name
":"cafe"}]}
V/WoorldsService( 6019): Received global message on com.goldtouch.ynet: com.woor
lds.data. intentVersion=17
I/WoorldsService( 6019): publishing data in com.goldtouch.ynet permission: norma
l
I/WoorldsService( 6019): Segmentation: [{"id":"554f6c37223599407e8b456c","name":
"cafe"}]
V/WoorldsService( 6019): no client is bound to this service
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
W/ProcessCpuTracker(  773): Skipping unknown process pid 12628
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
I/ActivityManager(  773): Start proc 12702:com.ionicframework.moneytunespoc64436
9/u0a217 for service com.ionicframework.moneytunespoc644369/com.twilio.client.Tw
ilioClientService
I/art     (12702): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/ActivityThread(12702): Switching default density from 440 to 480
I/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:37.159 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.3 for POSIX initialized
D/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:37.164 sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
I/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:37.166          pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0xb
4ad8044)
I/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:37.166 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" register
ed
D/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:37.166 sip_transport.  .Transport manager created.
I/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:37.166   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> C
REATED
D/ConnectivityService(  773): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () -
 101] to 59
D/ConnectivityService(  773): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]
D/ConnectivityService(  773): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101] was alrea
dy satisfying request 1. No change.
D/ConnectivityService(  773): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI ()
 - 101]
D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 1166): CM callback handler got msg 524290

D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
E/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:39.294  tsx0xb48c6864  Failed to send Request msg REGIS
TER/cseq=2541 (tdta0xb4af9000)! err=320046 (No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTI
L_EDNSNOWORKINGNS))
E/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:39.295    pjsua_acc.c  ..SIP registration failed, statu
s=503 (No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS))
D/ConnectivityService(  773): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () -
 101] to 55
D/ConnectivityService(  773): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101]
D/ConnectivityService(  773): Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101] was alrea
dy satisfying request 1. No change.
D/ConnectivityService(  773): notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI ()
 - 101]
D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 1166): CM callback handler got msg 524290

I/MediaFocusControl(  773):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.
AudioManager@7008991com.cyanogenmod.eleven.MusicPlaybackService$5@1c4af0f6
I/HeadsetService( 1564): Audio session removed: 18
D/NuPlayerDriver(  250): reset(0xb5bc60a0)
D/NuPlayerDriver(  250): notifyResetComplete(0xb5bc60a0)
I/MediaFocusControl(  773):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.
AudioManager@7008991com.cyanogenmod.eleven.MusicPlaybackService$5@1c4af0f6
I/ActivityManager(  773): Killing 2061:com.cyanogenmod.eleven:main/u0a39 (adj 15
): empty #17
D/NuPlayerDriver(  250): reset(0xb5943e20)
D/NuPlayerDriver(  250): notifyResetComplete(0xb5943e20)
V/ActivityManager(  773): killProcessGroupAsync took 46 ms for PID 2061 on threa
d 17
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
E/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:49.257  tsx0xb48c6864  ..Failed to send Request msg REG
ISTER/cseq=40614 (tdta0xb4af9000)! err=320046 (No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_
UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS))
E/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:49.257    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, sta
tus=503 (No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS))
F/PJSIP   (12702): 19:09:49.259    pjsua_acc.c  .Unable to create/send REGISTER:
 No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS) [status=320046]
D/Ulp_jni (  773): Location CB invoked
E/PushSDK ( 4036): read err :recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by pe
er)
W/System.err( 4036): read err :recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by
peer)
I/ActivityManager(  773): Killing 11578:com.google.android.apps.cloudprint/u0a54
 (adj 15): empty #17
V/ActivityManager(  773): killProcessGroupAsync took 47 ms for PID 11578 on thre
ad 17
```

I see there is an overflow and android chose to close the "suspicious" app due to its high memory usage. It might have something to do with the speaker as well,
Any help is welcome!